# GCM Network Manager, are multiple one off tasks exeucted in sequential order?

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

**Introduction**

I have an app which let's the user favourite a list of music albums. The music albums content are stored on the device to allow offline access.

The favourite choices are also stored offline via local SQLite database

If the internet is active the favourite request call happens as normal however, I would like to support this in offline mode.

I came across the GCM Network Manager which will allow me to schedule a task when the network is active so every favourite request that is made offline will be scheduled.

**The problem & my questions**

I've gone through the documentations and searched but I cannot find the answers to these questions.

1. Can I submit multiple one-off tasks that have the same tag and ensure they are not overridden? I ask this because the docs say `setUpdateCurrent` method of the one off task builder classis by default false to suggest it is not overridden. However, the `setTag` method states that if the tag is the same the pre-existing task will be updated which is not what I want. **I want to queue up the same task because they would be unique music album favourite request**
2. I reliased that the above can be solved by setting a tag of the music album ID which I have but what I do not know is what order does the GCM Job manager execute its tasks. I use an example

Here are two tasks, they have unique tags, the first was submitted first and then shortly after the second.

- **Tag =** 1A-favourite

  - **Tag =** 1A-unfavourite

Will the GCM Network manager execute these tasks in the order they were submitted? It might cause a problem if unfavourite request was made before favourite.

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
gcmNetworkManager.cancelTask("1A-favourite", MyTask.class);
gcmNetworkManager.schedule(myUnFavoriteTask);
```

That should ensure that your first request was either cancelled before it could get sent, or that it has completed successfully, and the second request will properly "un-favorite" the item in question.

Also, you should only see tasks replacing each other if their tags are identical and you .setUpdateCurrent(true) on the builder. As you pointed out, it defaults to false.